# Right way to use "Cannot but help"

Tags: conditional-perfect

A relatively straightforward use of *"cannot but help"* is along the lines of

> When you use ... you cannot but help notice...

No issues there.  However, I would like to say

> If you have used ... (right form of) you cannot but help notice

I could simply duck the issue and write

> If you have used ... you will have noticed

but not being able to work in *cannot but help* is bothering me.  I'd be most grateful to anyone who might be able to tell me how it could be used with "If you have..."

Comment: Simpler and more common is _You can't help noticing_.

Comment: If I had felt that in the context I could get away with _You can't help noticing_ I would have done so

Comment: If the word order is what you say, that is your problem right there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are mistaken.  The correct form of the expression is "**cannot help but**".

A correct sentence would be: "If you have used the soap, you cannot have helped but notice the odor it has."

Comment: you are right, it should be **cannot help but** not _cannot but help_.  I guess my issues started with me switching the two words.

Answer (score 1):

There is no correct way to use "cannot help but."  There are two traditional and synonymous idioms, "cannot but [do something]" and "cannot help [doing something]."  Those who say "cannot help but" are conflating the two (in much the same some people conflate "irrespective" and "regardless" to create the nonsensical "irregardless").

In an earlier posting of the same question (now closed), someone very helpfully gave a link to this [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cannot%20but%2Ccannot%20help%20but%2C%20cannot%20help&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), which helpfully demonstrates that while the use of "cannot but" and "cannot help" has become steadily less frequent since the 18th century, while "cannot help but" has grown slowly since the start of the 20th, use of each of the first two still comfortably outstrips the third.

That said, "cannot help but" has become common enough that many people won't even notice, but those who do may dismiss the speaker as poorly educated and/or not focused on the meaning of his words.

As for correct usage, either "I cannot but deplore ..." or "I cannot help deploring ... careless use of language" will suffice.